# Azure MySQL Single Server - Execute SQL Scripts using Azure CLI

Tags: mysql, azure

We are using both the below versions of Azure MySQL

1. **Azure Database for MySQL single server** (deprecates in 2024)
2. **Azure Database for MySQL Flexible server**

For Option #1 above (Flexible), we are able to execute the SQL Scripts from Azure CLI. However, I couldn't find any option to execute the SQL Scripts for Option1 (Single Server).

Is there any command to execute SQL Scripts (from a .sql file)  to **Azure Database for MySQL single server**?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

To connect Azure Database for MySQL - Single Server you can use popular client tool, **[mysql.exe](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)** command-line tool with [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

To execute script on Azure Database for MySQL - Single Server you can use following command on your cli.
**MyScript:**

```sql
use databasename;
CREATE  TABLE  Persons2 (PersonID int,LastName varchar(255),FirstName varchar(255));
```

**Sample Command:**

```
mysql -h servername.mysql.database.azure.com -u username@servername -p databasename < file_path
```

**File Executed:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]